# SignalR HTTP status code 406 for auto generated hub

Tags: signalr

I have a problem I can't get my head around. On some pages of our website we use SignalR. Recently some clients, notably our clients that use our website from behind a corporate proxy/firewall, have issues with the SignalR pages. They cannot load the /signalr/hubs script, a HTTP status code 406 is returned.

For example, when one of our clients requests the page from a cloud environment, this is the result:
[image: HTTP status 406]

If I request the same page, it loads fine:
[image: HTTP status 200]

I can't explain why it would give a 406 status code, `accept: */*` and `accept-language` should do the trick. The only notable difference I see is the disabled caching in the 2nd image.

The necessary scripts are in the proper order:

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Collectief/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Collectief/signalr/hub"></script>
```

Has anybody encountered this issue? Would it help to disable the auto-generated hub script and generate a physical file as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the call to /Collectief/signalr/hub never reached our server, and was blocked by the corporate firewall of our client. They had a barracuda firewall. It seems that some firewall manufacturers (maybe more than just barracuda) have updated their filters and are now blocking SignalR functionality.

We replaced the autogenerated /signalr/hub with a physical file to circumvent the issue, but then the negotiate call would fail with another 406 status code.

We now tell our clients to change the firewall settings: whitelist our site or allow all SignalR calls.